# SQL Server : trouble with ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble in calculating the maximum of a `row_number` in my sql statement.

I query search `OriginalDocumentNumber` but data is not the same with query all
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwVN9.png

```
select 
    OriginalDocumentNumber, FilterRound, p2_Reason, rowno, p2_FinalGrade
from 
    (select  * ,row_number() over (partition by OriginalDocumentNumber,FilterRound order by p2_FinalGrade desc) rowno 
                from #TempDa 
            ) l  
        where  
        l.p2_FinalGrade in ('d','f')  
         and l.rowno = 1
         and l.OriginalDocumentNumber='590200054'
         and l.OriginalDocumentNumber+l.FilterRound not in (select OriginalDocumentNumber+FilterRound from #TempDa where p2_FinalGrade in ('a','b','c'))
```

query 2 output [image query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E1jR.png)

```
select OriginalDocumentNumber ,FilterRound ,  p2_Reason , rowno , p2_FinalGrade
            from (
                    select * ,row_number() over (partition by OriginalDocumentNumber,FilterRound order by p2_FinalGrade desc) rowno 
                    from #TempDa 
                ) l  
            where  
            l.p2_FinalGrade in ('d','f')  
             and l.rowno = 1
             -- and l.OriginalDocumentNumber='590200054'
             and l.OriginalDocumentNumber+l.FilterRound not in (select OriginalDocumentNumber+FilterRound from #TempDa where p2_FinalGrade in ('a','b','c'))
```

Comment: what is the issue here ?

Comment: your and clause is commented out .could you clarify on exactly what you are tying to seek

Comment: my sql or sql-server?

Comment: You need to specify what your problem is.